# Initializing an variable matrix in a structure C

Tags: c

How I can initialize an element in a struct? I have this struct:

```
typedef struct { int mat[x][x]; int res; } graphe;
graphe g;
```

I was expecting this to work:

```
g.mat = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}};
```

but it does not.

Comment: You'll need to elaborate on what "doesn't work".

Comment: It looks like you meant: `g.mat = {{{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}};`. That is, another set of braces to initialize array.

Comment: Assignment and initialization are different concepts in C. You are not initializing but assigning.

Comment: @0x499602D2 brace-enclosed initializers can't be used for assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that arrays are not assignable, and by the time you want to set `g.mat`, it has already been default initialized. What you are attempting is to *assign* values to the members of an existing instance. A lesser problem is some missing braces.

Instead of default-initializing `g` and then attempting to *assign* values to its members, you can *initialize* the `graphe` object with the desired values for the members:

```
graphe g = {{{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}};
```

This will also implicitly initialize `g.res` to `0`, but you can also initialize it to a specific value:

```
graphe g = {{{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 42};
```

Here's an example using [*designated initializers*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html). This might be easier to read than the previous examples, and you can change the order of the fields:

```
graphe g = { .mat = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, .res = 42};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can *initialize* your `g` at the point of definition, as shown in @juanchopanza's answer.

However, you can also *assign* a new value to `g` later (if the need arises) by using a similar syntax in combination with the *compound literal* feature of C language

```
g = (graphe) { { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 0, 1 } }, 42 };
```

Note that the assignment operator will only work for the entire struct object. If you want to assign a new value only to the `g.mat` array, not touching any other fields of `g`, then the assignment operator won't work for that purpose since arrays in C are not assignable. However, you can still use `memcpy` in combination with a compound literal to copy new values into `g.mat`

```
memcpy(g.mat, (int [x][x]) { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 0, 1 } }, sizeof g.mat);
```

This is actually what you tried to do in your question.